# Search for tags with wildcards but exclude one

Tags: support, tags, search, tag-search, wildcards

I will very often trawl [Super User](http://superuser.com) for questions that are really for [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com). Virtually any of Google's services are fair game for migration (assuming they're decent questions), so I do a wildcard search for tags:

```
[google*]
```

This works fine. However, Google Chrome is a browser and, as such, is perfectly on-topic at Super User (and off-topic at Web Apps). Therefore, I'd like to find all of the questions tagged with some variation of `google` *except* `google-chrome`.

```
[google*] -[google-chrome]
```

Does *not* work.

Is there a way to do what I want? Or do I have to resign myself to cluttering up my "favorite" tags with a couple dozen `[google-*]` tags? (Which I don't really want, as I also use Super User as an asker and answerer of questions.)

Answer (score 4):

Just search [google*] and hit enter. Then you can delete [google-chrome] from that string the software puts into the search box.

Comment: That'll work in theory. However, the resulting string in the search box is too long. (339 characters with a max of 240.) So, useful in general, but not useful in my specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`( [google*] ) -[google-chrome]`](https://superuser.com/search?q=%28+%5Bgoogle*%5D+%29+-%5Bgoogle-chrome%5D) - mind the parentheses and opening space! The parentheses corral the wildcard's expansion, and once that expression is done, any questions with [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) are removed. For extra fun, the exclusion can *also* be a wildcard: [`( [google*] ) ( -[*google-chrome*] )`](https://superuser.com/search?q=%28+%5Bgoogle*%5D+%29+%28+-%5B*google-chrome*%5D+%29) (parentheses optional)

Unlike a vanilla tag search, this will return both questions and answers. If that's undesired behavior simply slap an `is:q` on the end.